# How to call member function using function pointers for a specific object

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
    public:
        foo(int yy){y = yy;}
        void f(int x){std::cout<<x;}

    private:
        int y;
};

void main()
{
    foo* obj = new foo(123);
    void (foo::*func)(int) = &foo::f;

    //how do I call func with obj as this?
    delete obj;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is amply covered in a hundred prior posts, the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and the [Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html), so perhaps someone thought you were just being lazy of didn't know how to type anything into Google. Me, I'm outright corrupt and prefer the reputation ;-)

Comment: I'll agree, but I've done that about 20 times now as a time saver, so +1 to cancel the vote out :p

Comment: @w00te: it's a sliding scale. Personally, I don't mind answering a concise question if the answer is also short, and often that's indeed a fast method. (In fact, the entire MySQL section seems to work like that.) The question probably hasn't got much "value" because there are easily-findable resources that cover it, but it's an OK question. I'll firmly keep my "no vote" on it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call it ike this:

```
(obj->*func)(42);
```

The first set of parentheses are needed because of the precedence of "apply function call" over the dereference-PTM `->*` operator.

You can also use `std::bind`:

```
std::function<void(int)> my_f = std::bind(func, obj, std::placeholders::_1);

my_f(43);
```